# Differentiable function and the limit as x goes to infinity

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0.$$

Prove: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x + 2) - f(x)) = 0$$

I know I need use the MVT somewhere in here. I know $f$ is differentiable on $(x, x+2)$ so $$f(x+2) - f(x) = 2f'(c)$$ for some $c \in (x,x+2).$ So if we keep looking at the interval as $x \to \infty$ then it seems that's all we need, but I'm not sure how to make it more rigorous.

Edit:
Am I on the right track here:
$$f(x+2) - f(x) = 2f'(c)$$
implies $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+2) - f(x) = \lim_{c \to \infty} 2f'(c) = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. And let us make it very, very rigorous, i.e. let us use the $\varepsilon$ definition.

So let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Indeed, there is some $c_x \in (x, x+2)$ such that
$$
\lvert f(x+2) - f(x) \rvert = 2\lvert f'(c_x) \rvert.
$$
Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)  = 0$, there exists $M>0$ such that
$$
\lvert f'(y) \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
for all $y > M$. So, for all $x > M$, we have $c_x > M$ and then
$$
\lvert f(x+2) - f(x) \rvert = 2\lvert f'(c_x) \rvert < 2 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon
$$
for all $x>M$.